# Authenticating an applet on Javacard and an applet on SAM (Secure Access Module)

Tags: javacard

I have written an applet in my java card and the other applet in my SAM. I want to create mutual authentication by sending random number created each side.
The model of reader is:

```
c:\>gp.exe  -all -d
# Detected readers from SunPCSC
[*] ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader PICC 0
[*] ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader SAM 0
```

I select applet on SAM ,create random number and send out. Then I select applet on java card creating string with random of SAM and new random creation by card and send the mixed random.

So I should again select applet on SAM to check the random, but as my randoms are in transient Clear_ON_RESET Memory, they gone.

I need random numbers in transient `CLEAR_ON_RESET` Memory.And I use `gp.exe` for sending APDU's.

Is there any way that I can have both SAM and Card selected? I guess there should be a way to have both them up.

Answer (score 5):

If you've got different (logical)) reader devices then there is no need to close the channel to either one of them while using the other. You should be able to use them concurrently, even from the same thread.

The problem is using `gp.exe` which is a tool not written for such usage. Please code an application, for instance using Java & `javax.smartcardio` instead.